# Running only a given amount of threads at any given time in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a (let's say) function in C++ that takes random time to return a result (from 0.001 to 10 seconds). I would like to run this function N~10^5 independent times. So, it is natural to run lots of threads.

My question, is how can I run only 10 threads at a time. By this I mean that I would like to start 10 threads, and launching a new one only when another finishes. I tried launching 10^5 threads, and let the computer figure it out, but it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps thread-pools and work-queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `std::async` and let the system manage the number of threads.

Or you can, set a limited number of threads (a thread pool) - preferably using `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`; There are many ways to do this...

You need to start reading documentation of:

- `std::promise`, `std::future` (`std::shared_future`)
- `std::packaged_task`

[C++ Concurrency In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition) has an excellent chapter 9 on thread pools.

One good advanced idea is to make a thread-safe function queue (the simplest such queue can be obtained by wrapping `std::queue` in a class with much reduced interface that locks an `std::mutex` before pushing and popping/returning the popped value) to which you push your functions in advance... Then have your threads pull from the queue and execute the functions.